# printf %f Segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, printf, stdio

I have this piece of code in a function. I want to print the value of `y` here.

```
if (x1 < 0 || y1 < 0) {

    // Vertical lign outside of layer
    if (dx == 0 && y1 < 0) {
        return GKIT_NOERR;
    }

    float m = dy / dx;
    float t = y1 - m * x1;
    float x = -t / m;
    float y = m * x + t;

    printf("Hello %s. You are %f years old.\n", "Niklas", y);
}
```

But I get a segmentation fault. It works with *no* value at all to be printed as float. I can change that to `%d` or similar, which works fine.

```
    int val = (int) y;
    printf("Hello %s. You are %d years old.\n", "Niklas", val);
```

Any idea where the Segfault comes from?

**Edit**: Complete function.

```
// coding: ascii
// author: Niklas Rosenstein
// e-mail: rosensteinniklas@googlemail.com

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "gkit/defines.h"
#include "gkit/utils.h"
#include "gkit/graphicslayer.h"

#define SWAP_IF_NECCESSARY(x1, y1, x2, y2)  \
    if (x2 < x1 && y2 < y1) {               \
        int temp = x2;                      \
        x2 = x1;                            \
        x1 = temp;                          \
        temp = y2;                          \
        y2 = y1;                            \
        y1 = temp;                          \
    }

/* Based on Bresenhams line algorithm. */
int gk_GraphicsLayer_drawLine(gk_GraphicsLayer* layer, gk_Color* color,
                              int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2,
                              gk_ColorBlendProc blend, gk_float opacity) {
    SWAP_IF_NECCESSARY(x1, y1, x2, y2);

    float dx = x2 - x1;
    float dy = y2 - y1;
    float cx = x1;
    float cy = y1;

    // Figure out where to start in case x1 or y1 are outside of the layer.
    if (x1 < 0 || y1 < 0) {

        // Vertical lign outside of layer
        if (dx == 0 && y1 < 0) {
            return GKIT_NOERR;
        }

        // The function's slope (m)
        // ------------------------
        float m = dy / dx;


        // Find the y-axis intersection (t)
        // -------------------------------
        // y = mx + t   =>
        // y - mx = t

        float t = y1 - m * x1;

        // Compute the root of the function (N)
        // ------------------------------------
        // 0 = mx + t   =>
        // mx = -t      =>
        // x = -t / m

        float x = -t / m;
        float y = m * x + t;

        printf("Hello %s. You are %f years old.\n", "Niklas", y);
    }


    int incx = GKIT_SIGNUM(dx);
    int incy = GKIT_SIGNUM(dy);
    if (dx < 0) { dx = -dx; }
    if (dy < 0) { dy = -dy; }

    int pdx, pdy;
    int ddx, ddy;
    int es, el;

    ddx = incx;
    ddy = incy;

    if (dx > dy) {
        pdx = incx;
        pdy = 0;
        es = dy;
        el = dx;
    }
    else {
        pdx = 0;
        pdy = incy;
        es = dx;
        el = dy;
    }

    float err = el / 2.0;

    #define SET_PIXEL(x, y) \
        do { \
        gk_Color* c = GKIT_GRAPHICSLAYER_ACCESSPIXEL(layer, (int)x, (int)y); \
        if (blend != Null) {                \
            gk_Color t = *c;                \
            blend(color, &t, c, opacity);   \
        }                                   \
        else {                              \
            *c = *color;                    \
        } } while (0)

    SET_PIXEL(cx, cy);

    int t;
    for (t=0; t < el; t++) {
        err -= es;
        if (err < 0) {
            err += el;
            cx += ddx;
            cy += ddy;
        }
        else {
            cx += pdx;
            cy += pdy;
        }
        SET_PIXEL(cx, cy);
    }

    #undef SET_PIXEL

    return GKIT_NOERR;
}
```

**Edit**: Complete stack trace:

```
#0 0xb7e68cb0   ___printf_fp(fp=0xb7fc3a20, info=0xbffff684, args=0xbffff6f8) (printf_fp.c:844)
#1 0xb7e63ab0   _IO_vfprintf_internal(s=0xb7fc3a20, format=<optimized out>, ap=0xbffff750 "\001") (vfprintf.c:1623)
#2 0xb7e6cc2f   __printf(format=0x8049da0 "Hello %s. You are %f years old.\n") (printf.c:35)
#3 0x8049143    gk_GraphicsLayer_drawLine(layer=0x804d008, color=0xbffff810, x1=-20, y1=-10, x2=49, y2=200, blend=0, opacity=0) (/home/niklas/git/c-gkit/gkit/graphicslayer.c:180)
#4 0x8049ba4    test_drawLine() (/home/niklas/git/c-gkit/main.c:46)
#5 0x8049c80    main() (/home/niklas/git/c-gkit/main.c:68)
```

**Edit**: Please note that `printf()` *does* work when putting it after or before the if-clause. I.e. Something like

```
    printf("Foo: %f\n", 1.0);
    // Figure out where to start in case x1 or y1 are outside of the layer.
    if (x1 < 0 || y1 < 0) {

        // Vertical lign outside of layer
        if (dx == 0 && y1 < 0) {
            return GKIT_NOERR;
        }
```

**does work**, but moving the `printf()` *inside* the if-clause yields a segmentation fault.

**Update**: According to *T.E.D.*'s answer, I've tested around a little and this is what came out:

The problem seem the be the outcome of the comparison operations (`<`). I can do

```
if (True) { printf("%f", 53.3); }
```

but I can't do

```
if (x1 < 0 || y1 < 0) { printf("%f", 53.3); }
// nor
if (x1 < 0) { printf("%f", 53.3); }
// nor
int x_smaller = x1 < 0;
if (x_smaller) { printf("%f", 53.3); }
```

Interesting is, that this works:

```
int x_smaller = x1 < 0;
int y_smaller = y1 < 0;
x_smaller = y_smaller = 1;
if (x_smaller || y_smaller) { printf("%f", 53.3); }
```

---

*Conclusion*: The outcome of the operations `x1 < 0` and `y1 < 0` tested in the if-clause make `printf()` fail. The questions are:

1. DAFUQ? Why is this happening?
2. How can I fix it?

---

If you are interested in the *whole* code, I don't mind sharing it. It's on [github](https://github.com/NiklasRosenstein/c-gkit). It's a Code::Blocks project. The only include-path must be to the parent-directory of the `gkit` folder.

Comment: Is there a complete piece of code (i.e. including the `main()` and all `#include`s) to test?

Comment: It's part of a library I'm writing and is dependent on many of it's contents. I can post the code of course, it's basically part of the Bresenham Algorithm and the code above should figure out where to start the line in case the given points lay outside of the drawing-area.

Comment: Have you determined where the segfault occurs by examining a stack trace?  Chances are good it occurs well past this printf.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Well, when the given points *are* outside of the drawing-area, it gave a segfault. That's why I made a `return GKIT_NOERR` at the end of the first code's if-clause in my code (so it doesn't crash when the if-clause runs fine). Second, see the edit.

Comment: @NiklasR The "complete" function does help. The code doesn't compile without the required headers, and there's no `main()` to invoke `gk_GraphicsLayer_drawLine()`.

Comment: @EitanT `gk_GraphicalLayer_drawLine()` runs when passing valid parameters. But when they lie outside of the drawing area, although the line goes through it, it crashes (because it accesses pixels that are not available) That's what the if-clause was for.

Comment: @NiklasR Also, what is the point of calculating `y`? Substituting `x` into `y` yields `y = -t + t = 0`.

Comment: @EitanT Hm, that's right. I don't need that value. Well, would've noticed that when it's finsihed. :D

Comment: Could it be that your dx is 0!!!  your comparison right before usage checks for 2 conditions with an and.  If dx is 0 and the other case isn't true, you could have a infinite condition occurring!!!

Comment: @trumpetlicks Nope, from the stack trace that `dx = x2 - x1 = 49 - (-20) = 69`

Comment: Try this: add `#include <math.h>` at the top, and use `printf("%d %d\n", isnan(y), isinf(y))` in the body. It looks like there is a condition under which your `y` would be a non-number.

Comment: @EitanT No, it isn't. Quote: *It works with no value at all to be printed as float*. See also the recent edit.

Comment: @trumpetlicks what are you talkin about?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight prints `0 0`.

Comment: @NiklasR What platform/compiler are you using?

Comment: does it segfault when first encountering the `printf` or do you run `drawLine` in a loop and it crashes on second iteration or later?

Comment: anyway, try commenting `*c = color` and then recompile and run.

Comment: ok, there should be something with writing to wrong memory addresses, but it could as well happen in the outer functions, so this context is still not enough, I believe

Comment: @unkulunkulu `drawLine` is called once. `*c = color` is *not* where the error is. To your satisfaction, I did comment it out, and it does not have any effect. My latest update contains some additional information.

Comment: @EitanT I'm currently on *Ubuntu LTS 12.04* (32-Bit) running *gcc  4.6.3* which was distributed along the OS.

Comment: @NiklasR, minimization is the way to go, start removing all the unrelevant code, or maybe a dichotomy is on option: just paste this code at the start of `main`, it should work, then advance it through the code to the point where it is now and find the culprit.

Comment: @unkulunkulu The whole code?! Or do you mean the `printf()` call?

Comment: @Niklas R - In your "if (dx == 0 && y1 < 0)"  You will pass right over this if dx == 0 and y1 is 0 or greater.  In your next line, you divide  dy by dx to obtain m, if dx is 0, then you end up with an infinite result!!!

Comment: @NiklasR, the start of the function, with `if`s and `printfs`, the minimal portion that doesn't work. You can explicitly define `x1`, `x2` etc and initialize them to known values that are passed to your function, i.e. make a code that doesn't depend on the context.

Comment: @trumpetlicks Shouldn't matter to `printf`, that ought to print infinities or NaNs fine.

Comment: @trumpetlicks Ahh, I see what you mean. I actually thought, the program will fail then ^.^ However, `printf("%f\n", 1.0 / 0.0);` prints `inf`. *Btw, how is `inf` represented in memory?*

Comment: @NiklasR, you want to know everything at the same time, good :D `inf` has a maximum possible exponent _and_ zero mantissa in float, this is how it's represented internally, but let's return to business :D

Comment: @unkulunkulu http://pastebin.com/NfBA76kY, works. This context is `main()->test_printfError()`, and the original context is `main()->test_drawLine()->gk_GraphicalLayer_drawLine()`

Comment: @unkulunkulu Ah thanks. :) PS: Would be good to know why I got downvoted again..

Comment: @NiklasR, right, move it line after line deeper. First of all, test it at the start of `.._drawLine`, make it fail here.

Comment: @unkulunkulu Oh ok. So what's wrong with the question? **THIS IS CONFUSING**: When I put the printing code at the very beginning of `drawLine`, the error still occurs. But returning after the printing-code does work fine! Does that mean, the code *behind* the if-clause influences printf so it doesn't work anymore?! O.o Thanks for your help, btw. :) PS: Maybe you haven't seen, but you can download the complete source-code from github (see bottom of my question)

Comment: @NiklasR, no, code behind the `if` shouldn't be the cause, at least, I haven`t seen such a weird behaviour. What do you mean 'returning after the printing-code' does work fine? I browsed the code on github but haven't downloaded it.

Comment: @NiklasR, this is the kind of 'please debug my code for me' question, not a programming question that can be useful to anyone else. I personally just like debugging weird things sometimes and I understand the frustration, so I'm helping, but stackoverflow is not a place for such things really

Comment: @unkulunkulu let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13064/discussion-between-niklas-r-and-unkulunkulu)

Comment: @unkulunkulu Thanks for helping me solving this issue in the chat!! Tell me whether you want to write an answer, otherwise I'm going to write it.

Comment: @NiklasR, you're welcome. Probably writing it yourself would be beneficial, so I'll leave that up to you :D

Comment: @unkulunkulu I've added the answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to unkulunkulu, who provided his help in the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13064/discussion-between-niklas-r-and-unkulunkulu), we were able to find the issue.

I couldn't believe that previous calls to `gk_GraphicsLayer_drawLine` could influence the behaviour of following calls, but exactly *this* was the case. In my `main()` function, I called the function three times. The first call recieved accidently values that did also reach out of bounds of the pixel-array of `gk_GraphicsLayer`. The third call was the one who finally crashed the program.

This also explains why exiting the function after the *if-clause* (where the error appeared in) fixed the segfault. It was because it prevented the function from accessing memory it shouldn't access.

**Summary**: Writing to the memory of an invalid address is *so much* dangerous, it can even trigger a completely other function to fail and lead you to miss-asumptions. Unfortunately, one doesn't recieve Segmentation Fault errors when the invalid address is still in range of the memory that was supplied by the OS for your application.

Comment: Yes, but only 2 days after posting the answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is exactly why I hate `printf()`. It is about the most error-prone routine in an otherwise error-prone language.

The first thing to do with a "werid" crash is to simplify the logic to try to narrow it down.

In this case, I'd next try setting your float to a known value (eg: `1.0`) right before the `printf`. It could be that your `printf` has a bug on some weird value that you happen to have in there.

If that works (prints `1.0`) then my next step would be to try to print the bits in that variable. For C, that would probably be changing the format to `%x` and the parameter to something like `*((unsigned int *)(&y))`

If it didn't work (I'm guessing not from your comment) keep simplifying. Try removing the `%s` and its parameter (kind of unnessecary ATM anyway). If that still fails, either try:

- moving your broken code snippet into a stand-alone "main" and then (assuming it works) add in code until it breaks.
- commenting out code from your existing code until you find something that makes it work.

Comment: Should `printf("Hello %s. You are %f years old.\n", "Niklas", 1.0);` work with your approach? Because it doesnt... Making `%d` instead works.  ._.' Ah, already forgot to tell that `printf` works in another context. I.e. outside the if-clause. Should add that..

Comment: my bet is that the `printf` itself is completely innocent here, stack must be broken.

Comment: @unkulunkulu - My suspicion too now. Performing either bullet in my answer should help pinpoint the culprit.

Comment: @T.E.D., right, performing that in the comments to the question itself.

Comment: The language is not error prone if you don't know it sufficiently well. It is otherwise. Don't blame the language. Blame its misuse.

Comment: @Alex - I don't disagree. But as someone who writes stuff actual users have to operate, one thing I've leared over the years is that if certian things keep screwing up your users over and over again, at some point you have to quit blaming the users and admit there's a problem.

Comment: Then perhaps the problem is not in C, but in choosing C?

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze - Yes. Although I find these days most of the time C isn't a choice, but something you end up with no other real choice but to use for some reason. It has become sort of the Denny's of languages. :-)